# linux find command unnecessary data

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to write simple bash script and I'm stuck with `find` command.

When I type `find . zad*`, I get output like:

```
.
./lab2.sh~
./#zad2.sh#
./zad2.sh~
./zad1a.sh
./zad2.sh
./lab2.sh
./Azad2.sh~
./cdlinux.ftp.log
./Azad2.sh
./zad1a.sh~
./zad1.sh
./cdlinux.www.log
./zad1.sh~
zad1a.sh
zad1a.sh~
zad1.sh
zad1.sh~
zad2.sh
zad2.sh~
```

Why does it list all files in my folder (with `./` before file name), and after that I get proper find results. Is there any way to remove that `./` output? Using sed command won't work in all cases (when search path would be different than `.`).

Comment: How did you get `lab2.sh` as a result of this?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - all files with `./` are in my directory. And that's a question, why is `find` printing that crazy stuff.

Comment: what is the _exact command_ you typed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `-name` flag to specify the name to search for, and enclose the pattern in quotes so bash doesn't perform automatic expansion on the wildcard `*` before it's passed to `find`:

```
 find . -name "zad*"
```

Also, you don't need to specify the cwd path with `.`

Using:

```
 find -name "zad*"
```

should work just fine =)

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now.
"Much to learn I still have" :-)

Answer (score 2):

First off, to search for a file by name you need to use the `-name` option. Second, you need to include the pattern in quotes.

The way glob patterns like `*` work is that bash will expand the pattern *before your command is called*. Therefore, find will be given all the files that match the pattern. Without quotes it's as if you typed a command like `find . -name zad1.sh zad2.sh zad3.sh ...` (depending on what files are in the current directory that match your pattern)

To prevent this, include your pattern in single quotes. This causes the literal string `zad*` to be passed as an argument to the find command, allowing zad to compare the pattern against each file it finds.

For example:

```
find . -name 'zad*'
```

Comment: When I type `find . "zad*"`, I get an error message `find: ``zad*': There is no such file or directory`.
I found a solution thanks to @sampson-chen, take a look at the post below.

Comment: @gogowitczak: you left out the `-name` parameter. So, the first argument was the literal string `zad*` which "find" thinks is the name of a directory to search. Since there is no directory named `zad*` it gave you the error.